# Query not executing using inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setup-project, pascalscript

I am executing a query in inno setup using sqlcmd. The purpose of the query is creating database. I have tried the query so far in sqlcmd which take a keyword 'GO' after after entering the query. The question is how to embed the keyword 'GO' after the query so it executes.

the pascal script which i have used is:

```
    [Code]
    Begin
         exec('SqlCmd.exe', ' -E -S Haider-PC ' + ExpandConstant('-Q "CREATE DATABASE Test"'), '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated,ResultCode);      
    End
```

Comment: Why do you want to *embed* `GO` ? The [`help`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) explicitly warns about not using it (see `-Q`, or `-q` parameter descriptions.

Comment: @TLama...i tried to run the setup a couple of times but it is'nt giving any result

Comment: The database isnt creating..

Comment: Forget about setup for now. First make it work in command prompt. Then move it to setup.

Comment: @TLama... what ever command i pass in sqlcmd it need 'GO' after pressing enter to execute the query then it works